# How to move from Git Submodule to Visual Studio Multi Repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, visual-studio-2022, multiple-repositories

Right now I have a main repo that contains and uses another repo as a submodule.

I want to move to VS [Multi Repo](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repo-support-in-visual-studio/) and I'm looking for a way to point my SubRepo's branch, same as Git Submodule uses .gitmodules file.

Is there a way to use VS Multi Repo and control subRepo's branch?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out more?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. I use VS MultiRepo and still uses git submodule.